# Deleting an object through an object handler

Tags: c++, pointers, object, memory-management, vector

I have an object_handler class that takes care of, well, handling objects stored in its vector.

```
class object_handler {
    private:
        std::vector<object*> m_objects;
        // ...

    public:
        void add(object* x_object);
        void remove(object* x_object);
        void update();
        void render();
        // ...
    };
```

The object class is a basic entity I would use in my game and now what I need it to do is for it to be able to delete itself when it needs (for example, when it's health goes below zero). One way I've thought it would work is if I gave the objects a pointer to their handler so that they can access their handler's remove function, but that turned out to be a disaster: the compiler started throwing weird errors (like "expected ; before * in "object_handler* m_handler""), I guess it's because they include each-other.

What would be the right way to store game objects and handle their deleting? It would be most beneficial if the object could delete itself while heaving the vector in mind.

One other way I've though it would work is if the object would delete itself and the vector would encounter an empty pointer and erase it but I don't know how good that would be.

Comment: Your "weird errors" could probably have been solved with a forward declaration. As to the "right way to store game objects and handle their deleting", this is entirely a matter for you to determine. There's no "right way" or "wrong way" for that sort of thing.

Comment: Careful deleting someone else's data. If an object removes itself from the vector while the object handler is iterating the results will not be pretty. Probably better to have a `RemoveMe` method or similar to notify `object_handler` that the object can be removed when it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you describe sounds like you may want to use forward declarations rather than full includes. This will allow you to have the `object_handler` class and your `object` class refer to each other by references or pointers in their interface defined in the header files. The actual full includes only then need to be included in the implementation (.cpp) files and the order of inclusion won't really matter there. For example:

File `object_handler.h`:

```
#include <vector>

// NOTE: No #include here for object class,
//       only a forward reference

class object;

class object_handler {
private:
    std::vector<object*> m_objects;
    // ...

public:
    void add(object* x_object);
    void remove(object* x_object);
    void update();
    void render();
    // ...
};
```

File `object.h`:

```
// NOTE: No #include here for object_handler class,
//       only a forward reference

class object_handler;

class object {
public:
    object(object_handler& handler);
    ~object();

private:
    object_handler&  m_handler;
};
```

File `object.cpp`:

```
// NOTE: #include both headers, order doesn't matter

#include "object.h"
#include "object_handler.h"

object::object(object_handler& handler) :
    m_handler(handler)
{
    m_handler.add(*this);
}
object::~object()
{
    m_handler.remove(*this);
}
```

Whether this is a suitable way to manage your `object` instances would depend on the rest of your code. The above approach is not that unusual. You may want to explore examples such as Qt's `QObject` hierarchy which has analogous classes to yours (see the [`QObjectCleanupHandler`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qobjectcleanuphandler.html) for example).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a flag `removed` (true or false) inside the `Entity` class. There I can delete them in the main loop.

Your example with the object removing itself should be okay too, as you can forward declare a class to break cyclic inclusion. But I wouldn't recommend this, as it makes when and where your objects are deleted unclear.

Comment: I edited the answer, tell me if there something to add again. Thanks.

Comment: Made a quick typo fix and grammar tweak.